# Saved layers styling settings don't appear in QGIS 3.18

Tags: qgis

I saved some label settings in QGIS, but can't see them when trying to apply them to other layers. Is there something I'm missing? What makes saved setting available (or unavailable) to other layers?

[image]

Comment: How did you save them?

Comment: With the "Save settings..." button at the bottom of the "abc" tab in "Labels" (in fact, at the bottom of the right window, in the question's screenshot)

Comment: So you saved it as a `.qml`, but not to the `.xml` which "supplies" the window you opened to the left.

Comment: Thanks! But how should I go about saving my settings as xml?

Comment: At the bottom right of your labeling window (not the style overview you've opened) hit "save settings".

Comment: Ah ok, this is actually what I did. Then they shoed up in the style overview window.